# how to execute 'gradle build' command from gradle.build script

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I want to execute a **gradle build** command from **build.gradle** file.

**build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
task me{
   //Can we perform gradle build command here.
       }
```

***Question:*** 
Can we perform gradle build command inside task me, similarly like we do from command prompt(screenshot attached)..?

> Note : I am using windows env, please assume I am providing all other statements in build.gradle file.
>   I am able to build from command prompt by executing

*[image: gradle build file]*.

I want to execute this task *me* from command prompt and it should be responsible to call `gradle build` command.(attached screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "call" a Gradle task in a Gradle build.

You might stumble upon the method `execute()` that each Gradle task has, but this is a purely internal method that **must not** be used by any build script. Using it will not work properly. It will not ensure the task is run only once, it will not ensure dependency tasks are run before and so on and so on, just *don't* use it.

Your code snippet is too big for me wanting to interpret it right now to understand what you want to do exactly, but if you want to "call" a Gradle task from another Gradle task, your logic is bogus and should be changed. If you want to run a Gradle task before or after another Gradle task is run, the only supported way is to use `dependsOn` (before) or `finalizedBy` (after) and you **can not** set these properties during execution phase of a task but only during configuration phase.

Well, there is one other way to call a Gradle task from a build script, but this is by using a task of type `GradleBuild` which would start a complete new and separate build of the project you specify which is most often not the action you really want to do.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you make the task `me` to a task of type `GradleBuild`

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.GradleBuild.html

E.g.

```
task me(type: GradleBuild){
    buildFile 'mybuild.gradle' //defaults to build.gradle so not needed
    dir 'someDir'
    tasks 'clean', 'build'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What approach I used was directly executing a Gradle console command. I prefer it because it's more versatile. You can do so like this:

```
task me{
    var command = "\"" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\gradlew.bat\" build"
    command.execute()
}
```

Another way is to use finalizedBy() method, which will execute specific task after the first one finishes. You can use it like this:

```
task me{
}
me.finalizedBy(build)
```